# <Link> (react-router-dom) does not refresh the page if it is on the same page

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a Search Component.
This is the way that I'm showing results

```
  {(search !== '' && filteredProducts) ? 
    (filteredProducts.map((item) => (
      <div key={item.id}> 
        <Link
          to={`/product/${item.id}`}
          onClick={
            () => {
              handleSearchSubmit()                      
            }
          }
        >
          {item.title}
        </Link>
      </div>
    )))
  : ""}
```

This works fine, except If I'm already in a product detail page (`/product/${item.id}`)
And on click on `<Link>` element the browser URL updates, but the detail page does not refresh.

```
  const data = useGetDataFromApi(${API}/products?limit=18&offset=0);
const filteredProducts = data.loaded && data.products.filter((product) => { return product.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) })

    const [search, setSearch] = useState('').
const handleSearch = (event) => { setSearch(event.target.value) } 


<Form.Control placeholder="Search" value={search} onChange={handleSearch} />
```

Comment: How do you load your "filteredProducts" ?

Comment: Where does search come from ?

Comment: you could force a reload if you wanted to with window.location.reload()

Comment: Please don't put code in comments: if people ask for more details, [put those details in your post](/help/how-to-ask) (and note as an "edit: blah does blah by blah" but by simply working those details into the post description)

Comment: Ok, but I need to avoid the force reload